# Is this slogan grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, british-english, speech

I've been wanting to use a slogan but I don't know if it makes sense. The slogan is:

*Never forget 2013, the year of great elation.*

It sounds okay but someone told me that I need to rewrite it as "the year which one experienced great elation" but that's too long and sounds like I'm trying to use "big words" if you know what I mean.

Comment: You are right, it sounds OK.

Comment: Huh, why is this marked "British English"? Do the Brits have some special sense of *never forget* unique to them? Or do only the Brits use nouns in apposition? Or could it be that *great elation* has an especially British meaning  unshared by the majority of the anglosphere?

Comment: Note that there suggested replacement, *the year which one experienced great elation*, is itself ungrammatical.

Comment: The long version should be "the year in which ..."

Comment: Slogans generally don't obey the same grammar rules as formal sentences.